# From first element to the last but one VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, my problem is to select range from the first element to the last but one, so for example I got range from A1 to A10 and i want it to be selected from A1 to A9

So far I know only how to select entire range which is `Set NameRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))` tired something along the lines `Set NameRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))-1` or `Set NameRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)-1)` but none of it works

I'd greatly appreciate help from you

Answer (score 1):

```
Set NameRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(-1))
```

should work.